# Android App Viewing Images Uploaded on Cloud Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage, android-developer-api

I have a catalog Android App that I am building to showcase different catalogs from different local stores. The Catalogues are basically pages in Image(JPG) format. I would like each store to have its own activity that launches a catalog.

From my research, I can achieve this by creating a storage reference to a storage bucket that holds these images on google cloud storage. I have created one storage bucket that is holding about 8 images of a catalog. I am not sure how to implement this connection to my app.

What would be the best way to go about this? Should I create a tabbed activity for the images to be swiped through and if so, how is this created and referenced to the images from the android studio?

Any help or resource on this would be highly appreciated.

I have already connected the App to firebase which is working fine.
I have the activity_main.xml layout file with all stores and upon clicking on a store the idea is to launch the catalog images for that particular store.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can see [Firebase storage quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage) which can give you an idea on how to setup your app. For displaying images, it would be easier if you use Firebase UI, [here's a link to the related documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md).

**EDIT**:
By the way, you are in the right track of setting different references to your buckets.